# How can I add a top banner in CSS without touching or adding any HTML div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to add a banner at the top of a website, but without touching the HTML file at all.
Here is the CSS code for the banner:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
height: 30px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #5d2c2c;
line-height: 0;
```

and I also have this code in my CSS file

```
h2:before{
content:url(https://something.png);
margin-right: 5px;
vertical-align: 10%;
}
h1:after {
content:url(https://smething.png);
float: right;   
}
```

and here is my HTML code which i am not able to touch it:

```
<head>
<title>A title </title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file.css" /> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<h1>header1</h1>
<div id="test">
<h2>header2</h2>

<fieldset>
<legend>About You</legend>
<p id="UserInfo">What is your name?</p>
<div>
<input type="text" name="yourname" size="40" />
</div>
</fieldset>

<div id="footer">  
<p>Thank you<a href="http://www.123.com/en">123</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using ::before in the CSS file for the banner code but the picture before the h2 becomes up with the banner and i cannot separate them !!
Can anyone please help me??!!

Comment: What do you mean "a mess"? What happened? Consider setting up a Fiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: can you create a snippet with your attempt?

Comment: @Utkanos Thank you for replying, I have modified the question so hopefully it is clear now !!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code can help: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/ardk8L80/)

```
h1{
  margin-top: 10%;
}


h1:before{ 
 content:"";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 height: 30px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #5d2c2c;
 line-height: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cat banner:

```css
#content:before {
    content: "";
 background:url(http://lorempixel.com/800/200/cats) no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#content{
 margin-top:220px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <h1>header1</h1>
    <div id="test">
        <h2>header2</h2>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>About You</legend>
            <p id="UserInfo">What is your name?</p>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="yourname" size="40" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <div id="footer">
            <p>Thank you<a href="http://www.123.com/en">123</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```